# Appcelerator. Alloy. Доступ извне к элементам view, созданной посредством createController и добавленной к другому view

Tags: android, mobile-development

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. 
Существует представление **row.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <View>
        <Switch id="search_switch" bindId="search_switch" />
        <Label id="search_switch_label" />
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

и основное представление

```
<View id="general" bindId="general">
 <Label id="testLabel" />
</View>
```

При добавлении

```
var control = Alloy.createController('row');    
control.search_switch_label.text = 'TEST';
$.parent.add(control.getView());
```

Все отлично добавляется, но как получить доступ к методам и свойставам `search_switch`?

`$.search_switch` - говорит, что "undefined"

`$.testLabel.text = '1234567890';` - Все ОК!

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто.
Необходимо добавить

```
exports.search_switch = control.search_switch;
```